# After I set file permission to 0600 on /etc/passwd, my linux vm failed to boot

Tags: permissions, passwd

I'm definitely new to Linux.  Build a Linux Ubuntu vm in Azure for syslog purposes.  Microsoft security configuration recommend /etc/passwd- file permissions should be set to 0600.
As soon as I did that, the vm will not be able to boot successfully.  It fails to start the networking services.  Is this normal?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Kit

Comment: Please read https://askubuntu.com/questions/827608/why-is-the-file-permission-for-etc-shadow-set-to-600   /etc/shadow needs to be 600 and holds the password hash. /etc/password needs to be 644. Please do not accept anything from MS as true in regards to Linux without finding other sources.

Comment: All processes, even something as simple as `ls`, run by a non-root user needs read access to `/etc/passwd`. It's the only place in the system where the USERID <=> UID/GID equivalence is kept, the only place to convert `~` to the user's `HOME` directory. `/etc/passwd` MUST be `0644`. Back in the depths of time, the password hash (the only sensitive information) was moved to `/etc/shadow`, which MUST be `0600`. Read `man 5 passwd`.